# How to get information from URL in Alexa using accesstoken?

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, alexa-skills-kit

My Alexa is linked to my Gmail account. All of the credential information is automatically filled out in Alexa. My Alexa skill automatically generates an accessToken every 45 minutes. How do I use GET to read the unread email content from Gmail? According to another post, I need to do something like this

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?labelIds=INBOX&labelIds=UNREAD&access_token=${accessToken}`

So what exactly do I need to do to GET url?

I tried

```
const REQUEST = require('request');
    var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?labelIds=INBOX&labelIds=UNREAD&access_token=${accessToken}`;
        console.log(url);
        REQUEST.get(url, (error, response,body )=>{
          console.log('............')
          var temp;
          temp = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(temp);
          console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
                //console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
          console.log('body:', body); // Print the body
        });
```

but it is not working. This is the error message.

```
{ error: 
{ errors: [ [Object] ],
code: 403,
message: 'Insufficient Permission' } }
```

Comment: This is an OAuth problem. I don't own an Alexa device so can you please answer - 1. Did you needed to create a Google Cloud app yourself which Alexa is authenticating through, or does Amazon automatically provide this functionality? 2. If Amazon automatically provide this functionality, does it have a dashboard where you can select the permissions for Alexa device?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved. this is the code that is working.

```
const axios = require('axios');
var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?labelIds=INBOX&labelIds=UNREAD&access_token=${accessToken}`;
        console.log('URL.......................'+url);



        await axios.get(url)
              .then(function (response) {

                console.log('response.................'+temp);

              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error...........................'+error);
              });
```